# SpriteKit displaying variable number

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

What is the best way to display some value (that changes as the game runs) on the screen in iPhone `SpriteKit`? The only way I can think of is `SKLabelNode`, but it's probably not meant to be used like this and also I can't find any way to measure its width, which makes me unable to position it correctly (I want it to be in the bottom right corner). Thanks in advance :).

@Edit

My attempt at doing this:

```
 SKLabelNode *someLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];

 someLabel.text = some_string;
 someLabel.fontSize = 30;
 someLabel.fontColor = [SKColor blackColor];
 someLabel.position = CGPointMake(some_int, 15);

 [self addChild:someLabel];
```

The values of `some_string` and `some_int` change as the game runs, so `someLabel` is removed, `someLabel.text` and `someLabel.position` are re-assigned, and the label is added again. Yes, I am aware that this is a bad way to do this...

Comment: Let's see what you have done so far.

Comment: I included my code. It's not how it should be though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, SKLabelNode is your simplest bet, it's just not the most robust tool.
You just want to update its text and its position when you need to. Your code is correct, and if you want to get its actual size, then you would get the width of its frame.

update text:

```
someLabel.text = theNewText;
```

update position:

```
someLabel.position = theNewPosition;
```

get relative width

```
float widthOfLabelFrame = someLabel.frame.size.width;
```

additional alignment settings that might help (vertical baseline is the default):

```
someLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeRight;
someLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeBaseline;
```

Comment: also keep in mind, that the frame.size.height changes based on the actual characters in the string, so if you have a j or a p, then attempting to center it will be off. There might be some better way, but I always load in a default string like @"wwwwww", get that frame height, and then use that value for all of my positioning calculations.